Access multiple opc-ua nodes with one call
Goal
Create an opc-ua method that has access to the nodes. My main goal is to return a list of nodes (e.g. all nodes in one folder or specific folders) with one server call, instead of one for each node.
What I've tried
I found this example of opc-ua methods that does work for me:
https://github.com/ifak-prototypes/opcua_examples/tree/main/src/MethodsServerSimple
But that one does not access the nodes.
Minimal non-working example
I created a minimal non-working example of a server that exposes two nodes (Node1, Node2) and a method sum().
from opcua import ua, Server

def sum_method(parent):
    val1 = node1.get_value()
    val2 = node2.get_value()
    return [ua.Variant(val1 + val2, ua.VariantType.Double)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4840/freeopcua/server/")
    uri = "http://example.opcua.server"
    idx = server.register_namespace(uri)

    objects = server.get_objects_node()
    
    # Add two nodes with initial values
    node1 = objects.add_variable(idx, "Node1", 5.5)
    node2 = objects.add_variable(idx, "Node2", 10.5)
    node1.set_writable()
    node2.set_writable()

    # Add a method to sum the two nodes
    objects.add_method(idx, "sum", sum_method, [], [ua.VariantType.Double])

    # Start the server
    server.start()
    try:
        input("Server is running. Press Enter to stop...")
    finally:
        server.stop()


and the client code to call the method:
from opcua import Client

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client("opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/")

    try:
        # Connect to the server
        client.connect()
        print("Client connected")

        # Access the root node and browse to the Objects node
        objects_node = client.get_objects_node()

        # Find the method node by browsing or by known ID/path
        sum_method = objects_node.get_child(["0:MyObject", "0:sum"])

        # Call the method, no input arguments
        result = sum_method.call()
        print(f"The sum of the two node values is: {result}")

    finally:
        # Close the connection
        client.disconnect()
        print("Client disconnected")


and the error:
opcua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNoMatch: "The requested operation has no match to return."(BadNoMatch)

My questions

How can I fix my error? Or...
Is there a better way to get multiple node values with one server call (or less)?
Are there examples (showing both server and client code) for this?


Don't use a custom OPC UA method to handle such a standard use-case. The OPC UA discovery services are capable to find the desired nodes in any way you like.
The OPC UA way to do this is to call the Browse Service.
Use the NodeId of the desired folder and you get the referenced NodeIds.
When you set the filters for "Organizes" references in forward direction and a NodeClass mask for "Variables" then you get all variables which are in the folder.
After that you can use the Read Service to read all found nodes.
Browse and Read (and almost every other service) allow to perform multiple single operations in one service call.
So you can get 100 values from 100 variables below 10 different folders with just 2 service calls.
